# In AWS is there a thing like a private elastic IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance with a stateful service on it (think database). It has an explicitly set VPC-internal IP address which I am using in clients.

Now I would like to re-instance, reboot or otherwise perform maintenance on that instance without clients erroring out. I could spin up a second instance and point all clients to the new IP address, but this way I would still need to synchronise both instances until the last client switches over.

In AWS you can have [elastic IP addresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html). This allows you to switch the instance an IP is pointing to. Problem is those are public (reachable from the internet). I want a VPC-internal IP address I can re-assign between instances. Is there such a thing in AWS?

Comment: Note that in a VPC an instance will retain its private IP address even during shutdowns and reboots. You would only need to worry about the private IP changing if you deleted the instance and replaced it with an entirely new instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by attaching additional network interface(eth1)to the instance which will be assigned a private IP. During the maintenance of the instance, you can move the network interface to the new instance.

Link:[docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html)

Comment: You are probably referring to Elastic Network Interfaces (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html). They do pretty much what I want except you have a small downtime between detaching the interface from one instance and attaching it to another.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak you would have that same small downtime window when you detached an Elastic IP from an instance and attached it to a new one.

Comment: People want to swap out VMs without changing the internal IP or having to reconfigure hosts that already refer to it. That is wholly and utterly independent of public or private. Jumping through configuration hoops with elastic network interfaces? No thanks, just provide me with a private elastic IP.  Why can't they make simple things simple?

Answer (score 0):

This should help. It seems you need to migrate to VPC 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-eips.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#VPC_EIP_EC2_Differences

Comment: VPC Peering:      
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As stated in the question, elastic IP addresses are public only. All of my instances are in one VPC, but I doubt that really matters.